# Oracle SQL - Finding the last date effective change between two dates efficiently

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, oracle-ebs

I am using the following Oracle SQL query frequently to find the last date effective change between two dates but it is not very efficient (full table scans). The primary key on `per_all_people_f` is `person_id, effective_start_date, effective_end_date`.

Basically for a user name (which does not store date effective changes) I would like to find the detail of the employee which goes with that user. Employee changes are however stored date effectively and therefore I need to find the last date effective change between the from and to date parameters.

Is there an Oracle index that works with between two dates? Is there a trick I can use to use the existing primary key index with the from and to dates? How can I write the query to be more efficient? Almost all queries I write will use this logic.

```
select fu.user_name, papf.employee_number
from   fnd_user fu
left   outer join
(
   select papf2.person_id,
          max(papf2.effective_start_date) max_effective_start_date
   from   per_all_people_f papf2
   where  papf2.effective_start_date between :P_FROM and :P_TO
   group  by papf2.person_id
)  papf3
on     papf3.person_id = fu.employee_id
left   outer join per_all_people_f      papf
on     papf.person_id = fu.employee_id
and    papf.effective_start_date = papf3.max_effective_start_date
```

Come to think of it Oracle must be wasting a lot of disk space on that `effective_start_date` and `effective_end_date` in the primary key index, since the only time they would be used is if you know a date for `effective_start_date`.

Comment: I can't understand, why do you need `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, a normal join should be okay

Comment: also, why cant you fetch `employee_number` from `papf2`, why are you picking it from `papf`

Comment: Not all users have employees assigned, hence the left outer join. employee_number is selected as an example, a better example would be full_name which changes when someone gets married.

Comment: A further inefficiency relates to the left outer join and the from and to parameters since I then have to wrap the whole query in a sub query to make the from and to parameters work (does not work with the optionality of the left outer join)

Comment: Join with `business_group_id` and it should improve performance marginally.

Comment: business_group_id joins are normally index disabled in oracle apps by adding + 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to join `per_all_people_f` twice, try ROW_NUMBER instead.

```
select fu.user_name, papf3.employee_number
from   fnd_user fu
left   outer join
(
   select papf2.person_id, papf2.employee_number,
          row_number() -- latest date first
          over (partition by papf2.person_id
                order by effective_start_date desc ) as rn
   from   per_all_people_f papf2
   where  papf2.effective_start_date between :P_FROM and :P_TO
)  papf3
on     papf3.person_id = fu.employee_id
and    papf3.rn = 1
```

Comment: Definitely helps, but still has the full table scans and doesn't really address my date effective woes.

Comment: @Superdooperhero: Assuming most of the work is finding the latest row an index (or partitioning) on `effective_start_date` might help (if it's selective enough). Obviously the join column is another candidate in both tables.

Comment: One would think that if it could use the effective_start_date index in sorting and finding the maximum it would already do so using the primary key index of person_id, effective_start_date, effective_end_date.

Comment: @Superdooperhero: The 1st column in your existing PK is `person_id`, how to efficiently find the max of the 2nd column? The index is sorted by `person_id, effective_start_date, effective_end_date`, do you expect that to be usefull for `ORDER BY effective_start_date`? Btw, this is not a real PK, because the table looks like a Slowly *Changing Dimension* and the PK allows overlapping date ranges.

Comment: Does seem faster if I change it to row_number() over (partition by papf2.person_id order by person_id, effective_start_date desc) as rn; but it might just be caching.

Comment: @Superdooperhero: adding person_id is superflous in ORDER BY because it's already partitioned by it. I doubt that Oracle will do a better plan, but you might double check

Answer (score 0):

This is another option:

```
select
fu.user_name,
papf.employee_number
from
fnd_user fu,
(
select distinct
papf.person_id,
min(papf.employee_number) keep (dense_rank last order by papf.effective_start_date) over (partition by papf.person_id) employee_number 
from
per_all_people_f papf
where
papf.effective_start_date between :p_from and :p_to
) papf
where
fu.employee_id=papf.person_id(+)
```

Note on performance: If you want to list all users and their corresponding possible person record changes within a particular date range, a hash join on both full data sets is probably the best choice.
If you have a huge number of employees, but not many of these have an application user, an index access suggested by `/*+ push_pred(papf)*/` might be better. If the date range is small and selective, create an index on effective_start_date to let the optimizer do a hash join of fnd_user and the per_all_people_f records fetched by that custom index.

To judge which option is best, don't look at the execution time, turn on autotrace and check which option has the lowest IO.